# Undefined variable: comment - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to show my News, it gets me an error when the news dont have comments. But when I want to show the news with comments it displays the news and the comments. Can u guess what my problem is?

NewsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\News;
use Validator;
use Image;
use View;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
// use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $news = DB::table('news')->get();

        return view('news.index', ['news' => $news]);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('news.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'body'=>'required',
            'subtitle'=>'required',
            // 'image'=>'required'
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,PNG|max:2048',
        ));

        // if($request->hasFile('image')){
        //     $request->image->store('public/img');
        //     // $news->save();
        //     $imageName = $request->image->store('public/img');
        // }



        $news = new News;
        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        // $news->image = $request->image;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            //Add new photo
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
                Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

                $oldFilename = $news->image;
            //Update DB
                $news->image = $filename;

             //Delete the old photo
                // Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }

        $news->save();

        return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News created successfully');
        //  return view('news.index', $news);


    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //

        $news = News::find($id);
        return view('news.show', compact('news'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $news = News::find($id);
        return view('news.edit', compact('news'));
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        // request()->validate([
        //     'title' => 'required',
        //     'body' => 'required',
        //     'image' => 'required',
        //   ]);

        //   News::find($id)->update($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'body'=>'required',
            'subtitle'=>'required',
            // 'image'=>'required'
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,PNG|max:2048',
        ));
        $news = News::find($id);

        // if($request->hasFile('image')){
        //     $request->image->store('public/img');
        //     // $news->save();
        //     $imageName = $request->image->store('public/img');
        // }

        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        // $news->image = $request->image;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            //Add new photo
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
                Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

                $oldFilename = $news->image;
            //Update DB
                $news->image = $filename;

             //Delete the old photo
                // Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }

        $news->save();
          return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        News::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News deleted successfully');
    }


    public function showNews($id)
    {

        $all = DB::table('news')->get();

        $news = News::find($id);
       // return view('coin.shownews', compact('news'));
        return View::make('coin.shownews', compact('news','all'));
    }
}
```

CommentsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\News;
use Validator;
use Image;
use View;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
// use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $news = DB::table('news')->get();

        return view('news.index', ['news' => $news]);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('news.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'body'=>'required',
            'subtitle'=>'required',
            // 'image'=>'required'
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,PNG|max:2048',
        ));

        // if($request->hasFile('image')){
        //     $request->image->store('public/img');
        //     // $news->save();
        //     $imageName = $request->image->store('public/img');
        // }



        $news = new News;
        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        // $news->image = $request->image;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            //Add new photo
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
                Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

                $oldFilename = $news->image;
            //Update DB
                $news->image = $filename;

             //Delete the old photo
                // Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }

        $news->save();

        return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News created successfully');
        //  return view('news.index', $news);


    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //

        $news = News::find($id);
        return view('news.show', compact('news'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $news = News::find($id);
        return view('news.edit', compact('news'));
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        // request()->validate([
        //     'title' => 'required',
        //     'body' => 'required',
        //     'image' => 'required',
        //   ]);

        //   News::find($id)->update($request->all());
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title'=>'required|max:255',
            'body'=>'required',
            'subtitle'=>'required',
            // 'image'=>'required'
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,PNG|max:2048',
        ));
        $news = News::find($id);

        // if($request->hasFile('image')){
        //     $request->image->store('public/img');
        //     // $news->save();
        //     $imageName = $request->image->store('public/img');
        // }

        $news->title = $request->title;
        $news->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
        $news->body = $request->body;
        // $news->image = $request->image;
        if ($request->hasFile('image')){
            //Add new photo
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('img/' . $filename);
                Image::make($image)->resize(300,300)->save($location);

                $oldFilename = $news->image;
            //Update DB
                $news->image = $filename;

             //Delete the old photo
                // Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }

        $news->save();
          return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        News::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('news.index')->with('success','News deleted successfully');
    }


    public function showNews($id)
    {

        $all = DB::table('news')->get();

        $news = News::find($id);
       // return view('coin.shownews', compact('news'));
        return View::make('coin.shownews', compact('news','all'));
    }
}
```

Comment.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'comment',
    ];
    //
    public function news(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News');
    }
}
```

News.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class news extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'subtitle', 'body', 'image',
    ];


    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
//comments
Route::post('comments/{news_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
Route::get('comments/{id}/edit',['uses'=>'CommentsController@edit', 'as' => 'comments.edit']);
Route::put('comments/{id}',['uses'=>'CommentsController@update', 'as' => 'comments.update']);
Route::delete('comments/{id}',['uses'=>'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);
```

index.blade.php (news list index)

```
@extends('layouts.admin')




@section('content')

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<!-- DATA TABLES -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<div><a class="btn btn-success" style="float:right" href="{{ route('news.create') }}">Publish News</a></div>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">News ID</th>
        <th scope="col">News Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Date Posted</th>



        <th width="280px">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($news as $data)
        <tr>
           <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data->title }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data->created_at }}</td>


        <td>

        <a href="/news/{{$data->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>

        <a href="/news/{{$data->id}}" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>

        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['news.destroy', $data->id], 'style'=> 'display:inline', 'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")']) !!}
        {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',['type'=>'submit', 'class'=> 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}</td>


        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myTable').DataTable();

  } );
   </script>




@endsection
```

show.blade.php (the layout of the news with the comments in it)

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')


<div class="col-lg-12" >
        <div class="pull-center">
          <h3 >News Details </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



<form>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Image Displayed</label>
                ​<br>
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/' . $news->image) }}" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"  />

          </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">News title</label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="1" disabled="true" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder=""> {{ $news->title }}</textarea>
      {{-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small> --}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Subtitle</label>
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="1" disabled="true" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder=""> {{ $news->subtitle }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Content</label>
        <textarea type="textarea" rows="5" disabled="true" class="form-control" > {{ $news->body }}</textarea>
      </div>

  </form>

  <div class="backend-comments">
        <table id="tables" class="table table-hover">
            <h3>Comments <small>{{$news->comments()->count()}}
            </small></h3>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th >Name</th>
                    <th >Email</th>
                    <th >Comment</th>
                    <th >Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
                  <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{$comment->name}}</th>
                    <td>{{$comment->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$comment->comment}}</td>
                    <td>
                    <a href="{{route('comments.edit', $comment->id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>

                    {{-- <a id="{{$comment->id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a> --}}

                    <button id="{{$comment->id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter_delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>

                    </td>

                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>


  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#tables').DataTable();

      } );
       </script>

    </div>

    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('news.index') }}">Return</a>





    <!-- delete modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="exampleModalCenter_delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Confirmation</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              </button>
              <form action="{{route('comments.destroy', $comment->id)}}">
                    {{method_field('delete')}}
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
          <p style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"> Do you want to delete the selected Comment? </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-button">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


  @endsection

@section('scripts')
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

    });
      </script>


@endsection
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through.  If you have an idea of the relevant bits that might be making your error, it might be helpful to others to just post those minimal sections.  E.g. you are looking for issues in display, so probably don't need to post the destroy() method, probably don't need to show the index view if there are no comments, etc.

Comment: okay sir.. thank you for that concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your code and find it out that you use `$comment` in `show.blade.php` modal (delete modal) which is not available here.

if you want to handle with modal you should use JavaScript otherwise you should include delete button beside of each comment (because of the `$comment` only available in your @foreach).